# Boost PropertyTree: How to read json array into?

Tags: c++, arrays, json, boost, boost-propertytree

So having such json:

```
{
  "config": {
    "name": "myconfig",
    "servecies": {
      "module": [
        "file",
        "Admin",
        "HR"
      ],
      "notModule": "MyNotModule"
    }
  }
}
```

How to parse `module` array into `multimap<string,string>`? and is it possible to find out if `module` is an array and notModule is not?

Comment: -1: You asked this question yesterday, but you apparently didn't like the answer. Boost.PropertyTree is not a general JSON parser; you cannot load any JSON file and build a Boost.PropertyTree from it. If you need a JSON parser, I would suggest finding one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a JSON parser. There isn't really anything in C++ that will do all the work for you, you must use an external parser (or roll out your own) and interpret the events as it steps through.

I have had a good experience with [jsoncpp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsoncpp/), and there are a few others listed on [json.org](http://www.json.org/) under the C++ section.

Comment: Boost PropertyTree has JSON parser inside of it. It is not general C++ question its about Boost PropertyTree.

Answer (score 0):

The boost property tree includes a JSON parser.

```
boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json("file.json", property_tree_root);
```

parses file.json and puts the root in `property_tree_root`.

The children in the property tree will have names, except those that are array elements.

This is essentially the same as: [Parse elements from array in json file using boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634309/parse-elements-from-array-in-json-file-using-boost)